# Cropping output of pdflatex to pagesize

Tags: pdftex, conversion, geometry, crop

I am trying to create square images with a fixed size in pixels in LaTeX to be used as buttons. So far, I got the best results using the `slides` document class in combination with the `geometry` package, run `pdflatex`, and then process the resulting `PDF` using the `convert` command.

I currently use this as input (I added `showcrop` to make sure I got the page dimensions right):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=0.5mm]{slides}
\usepackage[vcentering,dvips]{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={1in,1in},total={1in,1in},showcrop}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tan^{-1}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This mostly works, but I want the resulting PDF to just include the region I have defined in the `geometry` command. Currently, a big page is output and processing is very slow when compared to using the `standalone` package (which has its own issues, see below).

I have tried the `preview` package, but then top and bottom are cropped.

I also have tried to use the `standalone` class instead, but then the output is cropped on all sides and for each text used as input I get different sizes. Besides that, `slides` provides the font I want to use.

Is there a way to have `pdflatex` output just the region defined with the `geometry` command (after removing the `showcrop` option)?

Comment: Remove the dvips option in geometry if you want to use pdflatex.

Comment: It was as simple as that. Thank you, you saved my day! If you make that an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? LaTeX isn't the best tool to create icons, perhaps a graphics editor (using LaTeX fonts?) is a better fit.

Comment: Now it already works perfectly. I just don't want to use an editor to create 60 icons for 5 different solutions, so I wrote a script to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the dvips option in geometry if you want to use pdflatex.